# Possible to make *some* symlinks behave like 'cd -P'?

Tags: linux, symbolic-link, links

In Linux, suppose you have a symlink at `/foo/bar` that points at directory `/foo/baz`.

Case 1: If you do `cd /foo/bar`,   you'll be in `/foo/bar/baz`.

Case 2: If you do `cd -P /foo/bar` you'll be in `/foo/baz`. (this is like a Windows Shortcut)

Question: *Is there a way to create a symlink (or something similar to a symlink) that behaves like "cd -P", so I can have some links that behave per Case 1, and others that behave per Case 2?*

Added: To clarify, there is no "problem"; everything works as it should. I'm asking if there's a way to do the following:

```
mkdir ~/test
cd ~/test
mkdir physical
ln -s physical symlink
[some command here that creates ~/test/NewThing]
cd physical
pwd # output is ~/test/physical
cd ..
cd symlink
pwd # output is ~/test/symlink
cd ..
cd NewThing
pwd # output is ~/test/physical
```

Result of all this is that ~/test contains 3 items:

- `~/test/physical` # a normal directory
- `~/test/symlink` # a symlink that points to ~/test/physical
- `~/test/NewThing` # a file that behaves as shown above

My question is - is there a way in Linux to create a NewThing that behaves as shown?

Comment: (1) If you do `'cd /foo/bar'` then you will most likely get `No such file or directory` or so. The single-quotes are the culprit. I guess you meant the command without single-quotes, this would make sense. If so, then what is the point of posting the command with single-quotes? You can [edit] the question and remove the unfortunate quotes. (2) I'm having some trouble with imagining a symlink that behaves exactly as you described. Please post shell code (involving `mkdir`, `ln -s`, `cd -L` and `cd -P`, `pwd -L` and/or `pwd -P`) we can straightforwardly use to replicate the problem.

Comment: I removed the confusing quotes. Please see revised question.

Comment: Are you aware it's your shell that handles `$PWD`? `pwd -L` is one of very few tools that make use of `$PWD`. The OS itself does not use it. I mean e.g. if `pwd -L` shows you `/home/…/test/symlink` and you run any program there then it will see `/home/…/test/physical` as its working directory and `/proc/<PID>/cwd` will point to there. My point is it's about the shell. You seem to want your shell to recognize `NewThing` as special, right? What is your shell then? Or is it about another piece of software? Please make sure there is no [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) here.